# Button Click insert with infusion portection

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have button click event where items from a textbox is placed in the sql table. my problem is that i can not resolved an error that i am getting. the code is as follows

```
var cntstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var cmd = "insert into FRQ values(@1,@2,@3)";
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cntstring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd,cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBoxtest1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", TextBoxtest2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", TextBoxtest3.Text);

                cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cnn.Close();    
            }
```

I get an error during coding that i have some invalid arguments but im not sure as to what i am doing wrong. I build this code to the best of my knowledge (im a beginner). Any help would be great.

The tip that VS gives me is that the problem is around this section of code

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd,cnn))
```

if that helps any.

Also any help with what more i can do to prevent sql infusion would be welcome.

Comment: Can you add the error message you are getting?  Also, looking at what you have pasted - you use a variable `cmd`as a string to hold your insert  SQL statement and then attempt to redefine it as a SqlCommand.  The compiler won't allow that.

Comment: i agree with joe. you have used `cmd` twice. try `using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmd,cnn))`.

Comment: for sql *injection* do some searching and start a new question if necessary.

Comment: @Joe you were right. I totally missed it. Thanks for the eyes. it worked perfectly afterwards.